# How can I add index number in the front of output when using grep?

Tags: grep

I am studying a simulated chemical reaction and hope to track atom motion. This motion was written in a big file with different timestep. I want to get the atom ID(unique in each timestep) in each time step. However, the output of

```
`grep -ni " 6557 " filename`
```

has different line number which is hard to associate with timestep.

> 1117:      O       6557    0.000000    0.000000
> 5189:      O       6557    0.000000    0.000000
>
> 21491:      Fe      6557    0.000000   0.000000

How can I add index number (NOT line number) in the front of output when using grep command? like below:

> 1     O       6557    0.000000    0.000000
>
> 2     O       6557    0.000000    0.000000
>
> 3    Fe      6557    0.000000    0.000000

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU cat can do this:

```
grep " 6557 " filename | cat -n
```

Alternatively you can do it manually with perl:

```
perl -ne 'print ++$c, " ", $_ if / 6557 /' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest ***awk*** solution:

```
awk '$0~/ 6557 /{ print ++c, $0}' filename
```

---

If you still want to deal with `grep` command - combine it with GNU `nl` command (used to number lines of files):

```
grep -i ' 6557 ' filename | nl -n ln
```

Answer (score 1):

I found using `awk` with `grep` in the following way gives you a nicer position of the number output and is quite readable:

```
$ grep fruit list.txt
fruit:apples
fruit:oranges
fruit:bananas
fruit:lemons

$ grep fruit list.txt | awk '{print NR, $0}'
1 fruit:apples
2 fruit:oranges
3 fruit:bananas
4 fruit:lemons
```